# How do I use a follower database for ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, database-replication, ruby-on-rails-6

We have a database with a read-only follower. We'd like to have ActiveAdmin queries use the follower.

I understand from [Multiple Databases with Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#activating-automatic-connection-switching) how to set up the primary and replicata database connections, and that there exists [middleware to do automatic connection switching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#activating-automatic-connection-switching), but there's little documentation about that middleware.

Comment: I believe this is all handled in ActiveRecord and should be transparent to ActiveAdmin.

Comment: @PiersC If you're referring to the behavior of DatabaseSelector::Resolver and DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session, that's not the behavior I want. We write constantly, it would never switch. I'd like to switch by route.

Comment: Ah, don't be afraid to dig through and patch ActiveAdmin::ResourceController. Might be better though to first dig through the Rails source for database_selector.rb and connection_specification.rb

Comment: @PiersC Yes, I've done that. Nothing springs out. Though I've been eying `before_action`.